# Android Async Tsk not Executing Properly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I just want to wait in a splash screen until my JSON is processing, but that is not happening.  The**onPostExecute()** method is executed just after **doinbackground()**. There is no time to load the whole JSON.

Here is my code.  I am getting List size zero first then JSON will start to load.

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        datalist = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.e("entering","Enter Inside");
        try{
            JsonArrayRequest billionaireReq =
                    new JsonArrayRequest(new ApiURLs().getAll_movies_url() 
                            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.e("response", "Response" + response);
                            //Initialize Gson obj to process jason response
                            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                            // assigning data in model class, we initializing this class as a array type
                            // because the response is in array format
                            HomeModel[] getResult = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), HomeModel[].class);

                            // this loop help us in fetching all the records of model class
                            for (int i = 0; i < getResult.length; i++) {
                                Log.e("response", "Model Values" + getResult[i].toString());
                                //datalist.add(getResult[i]);
                                datalist.add(getResult[i]);
                            }

                            //GlobalData.setGlobal_movie_list(datalist);
                            Log.e("DataLoded","Record Added");
                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("Request","Error" + error);
                        }
                    });

            //This is a queue which is used by Volley to lineup requests
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(billionaireReq);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error","Error"+e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.e("Data","DataSize"+datalist.size());

    }
}
```

Comment: I think Volley requests are already asynchronous So do not need an `AsyncTask`. Just make it a simple method and do your stuff inside ` onResponse(JSONArray response)`.

Comment: @ADM you just wrote the answer as comment

Comment: Yeah  .. Only if OP got it .that what he/she is doing wrong here .

Comment: It would execute like that most of the time. In `postExecute` you are referring to result of another asynchronous operation, which might not be completed at the time. You need to change your strategy here.